# How do I give the right path for fopen() function?

Tags: magento-1, csv

I want to create (write) a csv file in a specific folder. the name of this folder is `attin_csv`. In the image you can see where is located this folder.
[image]

This is my code:

```
  $csv[0] = $header;
    //Creating attributes csv file
    $file = fopen("../attin_csv/attributes.csv","w+");
    foreach ($csv as $line){
        fputcsv($file,explode('%%',$line),"^","`");
    }
```

Comment: all of you give me the right answer, which of you should i marked as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use  `Mage::getBaseDir()` which give you  magento root dir.But it should be if you  in `magento file` or you have using `include Mage.php on your script`.

then

```
$file = fopen("../attin_csv/attributes.csv","w+");
```

I should be like

```
$file = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir()."attin_csv".DS."attributes.csv","w+");
```

See more at http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories

Comment: it is working without DS. What is DS?

Comment: Ds give directory sepreator. '/' create issue on window system

Comment: The base dir always already has a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below

Also please add before

```
// set require path as you have present
    require 'app/Mage.php';
    $app = Mage::app('default');


$csv[0] = $header;
    //Creating attributes csv file
    $file = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir() . DS ."attin_csv/attributes.csv","w+");
    foreach ($csv as $line){
        fputcsv($file,explode('%%',$line),"^","`");
    }
```

**DS : directory separate like '/'** if working without it remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This would be `Mage::getBaseDir() . 'attin_csv/'`

But if you have any influence on the location of this directory, you should follow the Magento conventions and move `attin_csv` into one of the following dirs:

- `media` if the files stored there will be used for unlimited time
- `var` if the file serves a temporary need (like `var/cache`, `var/import` or `var/export`)

Comment: @good.. idea ..

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use `fopen` and `fputcsv` directly since Magento has some methods that are easier to use ....

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir() . 'attin_csv';
$file = 'attributes.csv';
```

Create export folder wither propper permissions ...

```
// create directory under var/export
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->checkAndCreateFolder($path);
```

Write CSV file ...

```
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->saveData($path . DS. $file, $data);
```